# php- how to return row with date comparison

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, date

I'm trying to return a row of information from my database where the current date is between the two days I have saved on the database, i.e. meaning they are still on holiday.
currently I have written the code below, but doesn't seem to return anything, even though in my database there is a trip where today is between the start and end date.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trips WHERE id =$user_id_session AND date1 < $today && date2 > $today";
```

in my db table, there are two fields which are date1 and date2 storing the start and end dates of the trip.

Comment: You need quotes arround your date variables

Comment: What is the type of `date1`, `date2`?

Comment: in the same format Y-m-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates are strings, so if you are putting the variables directly into your query (which you shouldn't, and should be using prepared statements instead), you would need single quotes around it.  Also, you may want to check if it is less/greater than or equal to today.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM trips WHERE id =$user_id_session AND date1 <= '$today' && date2 >= '$today'";
```

Also, if your user ID session variable is a string, you'll need single quotes around it too.

Comment: @eth3king No problem.  It's usually something small like that, from my own experience.  :)

Comment: @eth3king Just a heads up, if you will, mark the answer as accepted (the checkmark).  It helps me obviously, but also shows others the question has already been answered.  :)

Comment: yeh soz, i was waiting for the time limit to pass before i could accept it as an answer, but forgot

Comment: @eth3king Yup, no problem.  I'm not sure why that limit is there, but I do the same thing.  ;)